# Kendo Grid with Checkbox as column changes the focus to first cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid created with checkbox as one of the column, whenever I check any of the checkbox the first cell of first row gets the focus, how should I restrict focus. Below is what I am doing on check of an checkbox.

```
$('#approvaltranslistview').on('click', '.chkbx', function (e) {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var grid = $('#approvaltranslistview').data().kendoGrid;
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    dataItem.set('IsSelected', checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is pointing on your `'#approvaltranslistview'` element

if you want to check your item clicked, use:

```
$('#approvaltranslistview').on('click', '.chkbx', function (e) {
    var checked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
});
```

Comment: I tried the solution provided by you, it didn't work still the focus is going to the first cell of check box, below is the updated code as per your suggestion.     $('#approvaltranslistview').on('click', '.chkbx', function (e) {
    var checked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
    var grid = $('#approvaltranslistview').data().kendoGrid;
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.target).closest('tr'));
    dataItem.set('IsSelected', checked);
});

Comment: here is the HTML code,  <div id="approvaltransgridview" style="height: 95%; margin-left: 10px">
                    <div style="vertical-align: top; clear: both;margin: 12px; margin-top: 0px; width: 98%;white-space : normal;" id="approvaltranslistview"></div>
                </div>